# C++ templates: can I call a function whose name is based on the input type name?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a codebase with a lot of enums associated functions that return singletons. Their names are formulaic:

```
enum Foo {...};
const MySingleton* Foo_Singleton();
enum Bar {...};
const MySingleton* Bar_Singleton();
...
```

Is it possible to write a C++ template that would choose the right getter function name without explicitly listing all the options?

```
template <typename EnumT>
inline const MySingleton* Get() {
  return EnumT ## _Singleton();
}
```

I know I'm using a nonsensical preprocessor directive here, but I hope it communicates my aim. I know I could write an overload for each enum, but there are a lot of them and it would be a pain to maintain, so I would prefer to avoid that solution.

Comment: The `##` directive is handled by the preprocessor. You can't do that with templates.

Comment: How about overloading `Get` using tag dispatching ?

Comment: You could specialize the template for each enum. But it'd have to be explicit (maybe helped by a macro?)

Comment: As I stated in the question, (1) I know `##` is not a template thing, I'm just using it to explain what I want, and (2) I am looking for a solution that avoids specialization for each enum. I appreciate the quick responses but please read the entire question first.

Comment: @RobertMartin how does `X_Singleton()` work and what is `MySingleton`?

Comment: @W.F. `X_Singleton()` is a function defined for every enum `X` that returns an instance of `Singleton` that has some info about `X`. Every `X_Singleton()` function points to a different instance of the same object (different for every `X`).

Comment: @RobertMartin Maybe instead of additional level of abstraction you could create different overload of `X_Singleton` with dummy parameter of enum it handles. I'm pretty sure this is what Arunmu was intended to suggest...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way. Why do you have formulaic names in the first place? It seems it would be healthier to have these functions as template specializations from the very beginning.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to change your naming policy:

```
enum Foo {...};
const MySingleton* Get(Foo); // instead of const MySingleton* Foo_Singleton();
enum Bar {...};
const MySingleton* Get(Bar); // instead of const MySingleton* Bar_Singleton();
```

The mechanism involved is called tag dispatching. Now you could get appropriate singleton instance by simple:

```
Get(Foo{});
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the possibilities:

```
// template specification (to be specialized)
template <typename EnumT>
const MySingleton* Get();

#define JOIN_IMPL(a, b) a ## b
#define JOIN(a, b) JOIN_IMPL(a, b)

// template specialization for particular enum
#define DEFINE_GET_SINGLETON(EnumT)       \
template<>                                \
inline const MySingleton* Get<EnumT>() {  \
  return JOIN(EnumT, _Singleton)();       \
}

DEFINE_GET_SINGLETON(Foo)
DEFINE_GET_SINGLETON(Bar)
```

By using macros you can save some typing (at the expense of debugging - most debuggers cannot step through macros).

Comment: If the solution requires one line per type, it's better to go with a fully template based solution.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt a solution mixing macros and template will be possible here.

A template-based solution that will work, but will require a wrapper function to be declared for every type.

First, define those functions:

```
const MySingleton* GetSingleton( Foo* var ) { return Foo_Singleton(); }
const MySingleton* GetSingleton( Bar* var ) { return Bar_Singleton(); }
```

Then just do:

```
template <typename EnumT>
inline const MySingleton* Get() {
  EnumT e;
  return GetSingleton( &e );
}
```

And then the appropriate `GetSingleton` will be picked up by the compiler, depending on `EnumT`.

Note, you can use a macro to declare the function, but I'm not sure it will be very useful:

```
#define DECLARE_WRAPPER(TYPE) const MySingleton* GetSingleton( TYPE* var ) { return TYPE##_Singleton(); }

DECLARE_WRAPPER( Foo )
DECLARE_WRAPPER( Bar )
```